# Rails accepts nested attributes attr accessible naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that accepts nested attributes for another model, like so:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner

  attr_accessible :owner_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end
```

I want to be able to call `:owner_attributes` just `:owner`, and be able to POST json that looks like this:

```
{
  "house": {
    "address": "123 Main St",
    "owner": {
      "name": "Jim",
      "age": 9000
    }
}
```

This seems like it goes against rails conventions, but I was just trying to figure out if its possible or not.

Comment: I believe if you are using rails 4 and post this that it will work.  If you are using strong parameters you just need to add `owner_attributes: [:name, :etc]` to the `permit` method of the params method. When it gets to the controller it will be converted from `owner` to `owner_attributes`.  So `params.require(:house).permit(:house_field_a, :house_field_b, owner_attributes: [])`

Comment: I'm not using strong params yet (coming soon :D), but anyways, I've tried just posting using `owner` instead of `owner_attributes` and that doesn't work.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: 4.0.4 (here's some more characters)

Comment: I would add the strong parameters to your controller then as a private method.  I'll post as an answer.

Comment: My team won't be adding strong params to our application for a while (yay Agile).  So this answer isn't really applicable to me.

Comment: Rails 4 uses strong parameters by default and will filter out the params not permitted as you can see here https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#handling-of-unpermitted-keys.  Also you can add this to your controller if you will be the only one using it and not affect the others.

Comment: You can use this if you really want to get around it https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes

Comment: So I tried your answer, and that doesn't work.  And I'm already using protected_attributes, what about it are you suggesting?

Comment: Can you add your controller code to your question above?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your controller

```
private
def house_params
  params.require(:house).permit(:house_field_a, :house_field_b, owner_attributes: [:name, :etc])
end
```

This will convert the `owner` parameter into `owner_attributes` allowing you to `POST` a nested `owner` object.

Then in the controller action you can just use `house_params` instead of `params[:house]`